# android instagram oAuth cant fetch user information

Tags: android, oauth, instagram, fetch

hey guys so i have aa working oAuth application and everything is fine up until the point at which the application tries o fetch the user information and it fails could i have some guidance on how to fix this? thank you

InstagramApp.java

```
    package br.com.dina.oauth.instagram;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import br.com.dina.oauth.instagram.InstagramDialog.OAuthDialogListener;

public class InstagramApp {

private InstagramSession mSession;
private InstagramDialog mDialog;
private OAuthAuthenticationListener mListener;
private ProgressDialog mProgress;
private String mAuthUrl;
private String mTokenUrl;
private String mAccessToken;
private Context mCtx;

private String mClientId;
private String mClientSecret;


private static int WHAT_FINALIZE = 0;
private static int WHAT_ERROR = 1;
private static int WHAT_FETCH_INFO = 2;

/**
 * Callback url, as set in 'Manage OAuth Costumers' page
 * (https://developer.github.com/)
 */

public static String mCallbackUrl = "";
private static final String AUTH_URL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/";
private static final String TOKEN_URL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token";
private static final String API_URL = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/21846697/media/recent/";

private static final String TAG = "InstagramAPI";

public InstagramApp(Context context, String clientId, String clientSecret,
        String callbackUrl) {

    mClientId = clientId;
    mClientSecret = clientSecret;
    mCtx = context;
    mSession = new InstagramSession(context);
    mAccessToken = mSession.getAccessToken();
    mCallbackUrl = callbackUrl;
    mTokenUrl = TOKEN_URL + "?client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret="
            + clientSecret + "&redirect_uri=" + mCallbackUrl + "&grant_type=authorization_code";
    mAuthUrl = AUTH_URL + "?client_id=" + clientId + "&redirect_uri="
            + mCallbackUrl + "&response_type=code&display=touch&scope=likes+comments+relationships";

    OAuthDialogListener listener = new OAuthDialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String code) {
            getAccessToken(code);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String error) {
            mListener.onFail("Authorization failed");
        }
    };

    mDialog = new InstagramDialog(context, mAuthUrl, listener);
    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(context);
    mProgress.setCancelable(false);
}

private void getAccessToken(final String code) {
    mProgress.setMessage("Getting access token ...");
    mProgress.show();

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "Getting access token");
            int what = WHAT_FETCH_INFO;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(TOKEN_URL);
                //URL url = new URL(mTokenUrl + "&code=" + code);
                Log.i(TAG, "Opening Token URL " + url.toString());
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                //urlConnection.connect();
                OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                writer.write("client_id="+mClientId+
                            "&client_secret="+mClientSecret+
                            "&grant_type=authorization_code" +
                            "&redirect_uri="+mCallbackUrl+
                            "&code=" + code);
                writer.flush();
                String response = streamToString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                Log.i(TAG, "response " + response);
                JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();

                mAccessToken = jsonObj.getString("access_token");
                Log.i(TAG, "Got access token: " + mAccessToken);

                String id = jsonObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("id");
                String user = jsonObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("username");
                String name = jsonObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("full_name");                 

                mSession.storeAccessToken(mAccessToken, id, user, name);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                what = WHAT_ERROR;
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(what, 1, 0));
        }
    }.start();
}

private void fetchUserName() {
    mProgress.setMessage("Finalizing ...");

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "Fetching user info");
            int what = WHAT_FINALIZE;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(API_URL + "/users/" + mSession.getId() + "/?access_token=" + mAccessToken);

                Log.d(TAG, "Opening URL " + url.toString());
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.connect();
                String response = streamToString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                System.out.println(response);
                JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
                String name = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data").getString("full_name");
                String bio = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data").getString("bio");
                Log.i(TAG, "Got name: " + name + ", bio [" + bio + "]");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                what = WHAT_ERROR;
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(what, 2, 0));
        }
    }.start();  

}


private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == WHAT_ERROR) {
            mProgress.dismiss();
            if(msg.arg1 == 1) {
                mListener.onFail("Failed to get access token");
            }
            else if(msg.arg1 == 2) {
                mListener.onFail("Failed to get user information");
            }
        } 
        else if(msg.what == WHAT_FETCH_INFO) {
            fetchUserName();
        }
        else {
            mProgress.dismiss();
            mListener.onSuccess();
        }
    }
};

public boolean hasAccessToken() {
    return (mAccessToken == null) ? false : true;
}

public void setListener(OAuthAuthenticationListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return mSession.getUsername();
}

public String getId() {
    return mSession.getId();
}

public String getName() {
    return mSession.getName();
}

public void authorize() {
    //Intent webAuthIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    //webAuthIntent.setData(Uri.parse(AUTH_URL));
    //mCtx.startActivity(webAuthIntent);
    mDialog.show();
}

private String streamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    String str = "";

    if (is != null) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is));

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            reader.close();
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }

        str = sb.toString();
    }

    return str;
}

public void resetAccessToken() {
    if (mAccessToken != null) {
        mSession.resetAccessToken();
        mAccessToken = null;
    }
}

public interface OAuthAuthenticationListener {
    public abstract void onSuccess();

    public abstract void onFail(String error);
}
}
```

ApplicationData.java

```
package br.com.dina.oauth.instagram.example;

public class ApplicationData {

public static final String CLIENT_ID = "My Personal ID";
public static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "My Personal Secret";
public static final String CALLBACK_URL = "http://www.yahoo.com";
}
```

Comment: How did you solve this problem?